# Attempt on charging laptop, spark sound happened

Tags: laptop, battery, ac-adapter

So I tried charging my laptop after an accident with some electricity, after a while there was a spark sound coming from the charging input. The laptop is running fine, is it a problem with the battery, or is it just the AC adapter which is messed up?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason people down vote this? I'm simply searching for help.

Comment: No one can answer this with anything other than a guess.

Comment: Well I honestly have no idea, I was charging my laptop when I suddenly heard a spark sound by the charging input. Nothing on the PC happened, but assuming something is wrong since random spark sounds don't just happen out of no where.

Comment: You were there and have no idea what it was.  Nobody else heard the actual sound, knows anything about your system, has no visual clues from inside the laptop, has no diagnostic test results, etc.  As you say, something went wrong because random spark sounds don't just happen.  Since this is not typical behavior, how could anyone else know what might have happened, other than to guess.  Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase, so unanswerable questions and guesses for answers don't contribute to that.

Comment: Well no visual damage whatsoever, but I got help from "davidgo". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details would be god and one can only speculate - A point of reference is that my cheap-and-dirty aftermarket laptop charger works fine when the battery is full, but when the battery is empty and it has to work harder it makes a high pitch whine.

It sounds likely that a capacitor has in your power supply has blown - this is relatively common in power circuitry, and could describe your problem.

Comment: Well there was a lightning strike which caused some electrical problems, the next day when I tried to charge my laptop (which I could do) I heard a spark sound from the charging input. I'm using the standard psu from when you buy the laptop, model is ADP-75SB BB and laptop is ASUS K52JU. I'd love to provide more specific details than that, but I honestly have no idea.

Comment: Problem is almost certainly with the PSU then - Any decent PSU is designed to die rather before a major spike through it.   This does raise weight to the "Blown Cap" theory.   It would make sense to swap out the PSU though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get a hold of a new one, then come back if problems still occur, will put you as answer for now (if that's allowed).